# is the grid method a good idea to use?

Tags: html, css

So at the moment I am using the grid method to arrange content on my website, it works very well for me as the responsiveness is very good and very easy (at least for me) to understand. But I am still new to web development and I enjoy using the grid method but is it the best option to use? is there a better method I could be using?

This is the sort of thing of how i would go around using it:

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cardTitle">
            <p class="overviewTitle">Overview</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cardTitle">
            <p class="castCrewTitle">Cast & Crew</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.card {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}


.cards {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(600px, 1fr));
}

.card .cardTitle p {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Grid is indeed awesome, but just like any tool you have to know when it's the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Grids` are very good and convenient, but there is also a very good layout method - this is `Flexbox`. I gave you a small example similar to your example.

```css
.cards_flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.card_flex {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.card_flex .cardTitle_flex p {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 800px){
  .card_flex {
    flex: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards_flex">
    <div class="card_flex">
        <div class="cardTitle_flex">
            <p class="overviewTitle_flex">Overview</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_flex">
        <div class="cardTitle_flex">
            <p class="castCrewTitle_flex">Cast & Crew</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that it also does a good job, I might consider maybe using that as well, but as @niet-the-dark-absol said, it is to know when to use at the right time

Comment: yes, grids and flex are each special and beautiful in their own way :)